# Dimension of solution space has 3 vectors but 6 components?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not understanding how this has dimension $3$, but there are six components in each vector.  If $3$ vectors span the space, why are there more than $3$ components in each vector?  I thought for a set to be a basis there should be $n$ vectors and $n$ components in the vectors so that we may express the set as a square matrix.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The space does have 6 dimensions as you pointed out.  The points that are solutions in that space, however, only make up a 3 dimensional subspace.

Using some smaller space examples we could look at the line `y=x` in 2-dimensions and note that the solution space is only 1 dimension (the solution is a 1 dimensional shape (a line) in a 2 dimensional world).

Or if we look at a plane `z=x+y` it'll be a 2-dimensional shape/solution in a 3-dimensional world.

Comment: So, its basically like a 3 dimensional object expressed in a 6 dimensional world? Like a sphere is a 2 manifold but it is expressed in a 3 dimensional world.